# Overhead of wrapping data in message

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

Will wrapping a protobuf parameter in a separate message give any extra runtime overhead?

This:

```
message MyData {
  optional uint32 data = 1;
}

message Container {
  optional MyData data = 1;
}
```

vs.

```
message Container {
  optional uint32 data = 1;
}
```

I'm only using the C++ implementation if that matters.

Extra wire overhead? Serialization overhead? Access overhead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a overhead for every embedded message as per [encoding explanation of protobufs](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding)

Below simple message with one int value would be encoded as `08 96 01`

```
message Test1 {
  required int32 a = 1;
}
```

Meanwhile encoding of message definition with an embedded message would look like `1a 03 08 96 01`

```
Test1:  
message Test3 {  
  required Test1 c = 3;  
}
```

Documentation explains it saying that

> the last three bytes are exactly the same as our first example (08 96 01), and they're preceded by the number 3 – embedded messages are treated in exactly the same way as strings (wire type = 2).

So in short `1a 03` is added as overhead into `Test3` since `Test1` is another message type

Comment: Thanks for the documentation reference